# Hiding lines of DOS output starting with a certain word

Tags: windows, dos, batch-file

I have a java program that I am running inside of a command prompt shell which generates a lot of output. Many of the lines start with the word "Prepared" or "prepared", and are not really necessary for me to see when running the program- they actually make it harder to see the data that I am interested in. Is there a way to hide any lines starting with these words while running the program?

Comment: `yourapp.exe | grep --ignore-case --invert-match "^prepared"`

Comment: Not to forget: one needs `grep` for this, which can be downloaded here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Doc Brown GnuWin32 is a better source nowadays. unxutils has been dormant for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pipe the output to:

```
FIND /V /I "string you want to omit"
```

This will remove all iterations of said string from your output.

Answer (score 1):

Change your program to use log4j or something like it, and then control which levels of message are sent to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
myJavaApp | findstr /iv prepared
```